# Load&Check ResourceDictionary Uri from EmbeddedResource in WPF

Tags: wpf, uri, resourcedictionary, buildaction

I need to load my ***ResourceDictionary*** from some assemblies at runtime.

First i set ***BuildAction*** of the ResourceDictionary with ***Page***, and use the code to build the uri.

```
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(@"/{0};component\Resources\MyResource.xaml",
 assemblyName), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

That works, but then i realized that, i need to check the assembly, before i set the uri to my ResourceDictionary. Because, if the ResourceDictionary is not in the assembly, that will throw a exception.

```
var rd = new ResourceDictionary
         {
             Source = uri
         };
```

So i set the BuildAction of my ResourceDictionary with ***EmbeddedResource***, in order to see the ResourceDictionary in the assembly with the code below:

```
var hasResource = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().
                 Any(resourceName => resourceName.EndsWith("MyResource.xaml"));
```

But now, i can't load the ResourceDictionary with the uri. I have tried all i can, but no success.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Still no solution here?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `Build Action` to `Page` and then you can access the assemblys Resource like this:

```
ResourceDictionary resources = new ResourceDictionary();
resources.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component\Resources\MyResource.xaml");
```

Then you can access the resources like this:

```
object obj = resources["key"];
```

Comment: That is almost like my code. That will also throw exception, if the MyResource.xaml is not in the assembly.

Comment: You're right, i have completely overlooked your assemblyName variable. How ever have you tried setting the build action to Page?

Comment: It seems, that you overlooked not any  my assemblyName variable ;- ) Yes, i have tried that at beginning. My problem is not to access the resources from Page. It is about to set Uri to Source of ResourceDictionary. There comes the exception, if Resource.xaml is not in assembly.

Comment: Are you trying to find out how to check if the resource is included in the assembly?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: What about catching the exception?

Comment: Catching the exception is the last solution... if i really find no any other.